# Find index of nested XML tag

Tags: java, xpath

suppose I have an XML like this:

```
<body>
    <nested attr="bla">
        <name>foo</name>
    </nested>
    <nested attr="blub">
        <name>bar</name>
    </nested>
    <nested attr="bli">
        <name>baz</name>
    </nested>
</body>
```

What I want now is a way to get the index of the `nested` tag with a certain value. So for example the index of `bar` would be 1 (or 2 if you count from 1).

I have already done this using Apache CachedXPathApi:

```
public int getIndex(String path, String value) throws TransformerException {
    NodeIterator it = cachedXPathAPI.selectNodeIterator(document, path);
    Node node;
    int i = 0;
    while((node = it.nextNode()) != null) {
        if(node.getTextContent().equals(value)) {
            return i;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Which works fine for getting the index from the attribute `attr` like this:

`getIndex("/body/nested/@attr", "blub")`

But I don't know how to do this for the nested values. If I use `/body/nested/name` then it will obviously only ever count the `name` tags within `nested` which is not what I want.

How can I solve this, either by changing the Java Code or maybe even with a special XPath expression?

Comment: Have posted an answer let me know if my understanding is correct and so is the solution.

Comment: Seems like your comment has been proved wrong about the failure of the XPath-expression solution in the case when no element matches the filter? If so, would you acknowledge this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just evaluate this XPath expression**:

```
count(/*/*[name='bar']/preceding-sibling::*) + 1
```

---

**XSLT-based verification**:

The following transformation simply evaluates the XPath expression and outputs the result of this evaluation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(/*/*[name='bar']/preceding-sibling::*) +1"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<body>
    <nested attr="bla">
        <name>foo</name>
    </nested>
    <nested attr="blub">
        <name>bar</name>
    </nested>
    <nested attr="bli">
        <name>baz</name>
    </nested>
</body>
```

the wanted, correct result is produced:

`2`

---

**II. Update**

In a comment the OP described another case, where there is no element in the XML document that satisfies the filtering condition. In such case the previous expression (above) returns `1` and this is incorrect.

Here is an XPath expression that returns the correct result in all cases:

```
(boolean(/*/*[name='bar'])) * (count(/*/*[name='bar']/preceding-sibling::*) +1)
```

This is the previous XPath expression, multiplied by another XPath expression (on its left) which evaluates to `0` if there is no element that satisfies the filtering predicate, and to `1` otherwise.

**The XSLT-based verification** shows that this XPath expression evaluates to the correct 1-based index values in the case when a satisfying element exists, and to `0` when no such element exists. Here we take advantage of the fact that the implicit conversion `number(false())` is `0` and `number(true())` is `1` .

**Here is the latter example**:

```
<body>
    <nested attr="bla">
        <name>foo</name>
    </nested>
    <nested attr="blub">
        <name>barr</name>
    </nested>
    <nested attr="bli">
        <name>baz</name>
    </nested>
</body>
```

Here no element has a `<name>` child with string value `'bar'`. And when we apply the transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "(boolean(/*/*[name='bar'])) * (count(/*/*[name='bar']/preceding-sibling::*) +1)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the correct, wanted result is produced:

`0`

Comment: I have seen the preceeding sibling approach before. Problem is that it the result is the same for the first element and for one which isn't in the XML at all. Both have no preceeding sibling so will output 0 (or 1).

Comment: It is the most elegant way though

Comment: @geanakuch: I updated the answer and the new XPath expression handles correctly this case. It returns the correct 1-based index if a satisfying element exists, and `0` otherwise -- exactly as an `index-of()` function would behave with 1-based indexes. Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: Yup, that does it. Brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood ur question correctly U want to have the index of the `<Nested>` tag in ur code, Look at the below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerException, SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
    String xmlString = "<body>\r\n" + 
            "    <nested attr=\"bla\">\r\n" + 
            "        <name>foo</name>\r\n" + 
            "    </nested>\r\n" + 
            "    <nested attr=\"blub\">\r\n" + 
            "        <name>bar</name>\r\n" + 
            "    </nested>\r\n" + 
            "    <nested attr=\"bli\">\r\n" + 
            "        <name>baz</name>\r\n" + 
            "    </nested>\r\n" + 
            "</body>";

    CachedXPathAPI cachedXPathAPI = new CachedXPathAPI();
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));    
    NodeList list = cachedXPathAPI.selectNodeList(document, "/body/nested");

    for(int i=0; i<list.getLength(); i++ ) {
        String value = list.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("attr").getTextContent();
        System.out.println(list.item(i).getNodeName()+" @Index "+i+" attr:: "+value);
    }
}
```

**result**

```
nested @Index 0 attr:: bla
nested @Index 1 attr:: blub
nested @Index 2 attr:: bli
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Thank you very much. I just realized that mine already worked but never mind. It's always good to have some input from the outside.